# How To Access Solution List Item from UserControl.ascx.cs SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listitem, splistitem, splist

This is my UserControl.ascx.cs partial class

```
namespace SP.ExampleProject.CONTROLTEMPLATES
 {
    public partial class ExampleProjectUserControl : UserControl
  {

    public SPUser currentSuperUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = this.ListItem.ID; // Can't use ListItem
        SPWeb web = Utility.GetWebWithSystemPermissions(SPContext.Current.Web);
        SPList Decision_List = web.GetList(Utility.GetServerRelativeUrl(web) + "Lists/Decisions");
        SPFieldUserValue boss = new SPFieldUserValue(web, this.ListItem["Bosses"].ToString()); // Can't use ListItem too
        SPListItem item = Desicion_List.GetItemById(id);

    }
  }
}
```

I can't use "ListItem" in this class.

So;

How can I access to my list items from partial class?

How can I use boss variable in ascx?

I wanna this because I want to compare currentUser.ID with boss.User.ID in ascx file and show special fields on template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    protected int GetBossId()
    {
        return new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, SPContext.Current.ListItem["Bosses"].ToString()).LookupId;
    }
```

Delete all. and write this function. And now U can get BossID at Usercontrol.ascx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get current SharePoint ListItem in user control, we can use the following line of code.

```
 SPListItem listItem = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
```

If the "ListItem" not meaning a SharePoint ListItem, I suggest you provide the code in UserControl.ascx file for further research.